# Hibernate JPA detached object is persisting

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA 1.0 (hibernate implemntation) along with MySql database.

```
project=em.find(Project.class,projectTO.getProjectID());
System.out.println("after find "+em.contains(project));
```

prints **`true`** as `find()` returns a managed state object.

```
em.detach(project);
System.out.println("after detach "+em.contains(project));
```

prints **`false`** as the object is now in detached state

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(project);
```

Here I'm trying to persist a detached object. So it should give an **`IllegalStateException`**. But here , it is giving **`MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`** as it is trying to persist an already existing data.

```
System.out.println("after persist "+em.contains(project));
```

it prints `true` as the object is in managed state.

```
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

**So My question is why detached object is getting persisted?**
Why am I not getting that `IllegalStateException` as per the documents?

Comment: How is the entity defined? Does it have a generated ID (`@GeneratedValue`) ? Does it have a version field (`@Version`)? If it doesn't have any of those, Hibernate can't distinct a detached object from a transient one.

Comment: @JBNizet i haven't used any annotations as `@GeneratedValue` or `@Version`. Beans are populated manually.

Comment: In this case, as I said, Hibernate can't distinguish a detached, already persistent entity with ID 56 from a transient entity that you want to insert with ID 56. Since you call persist(), it assumes that it's transient and tries to insert it.

Comment: @JBNizet So what should i do to rectify this.? Can you please elaborate that 'distinguishing between transient and detached object' .

Comment: I give you an object. How can you know if it exists in the database or not? You can if the ID is configured to be autogenerated: if the object has an ID, it exists in the database. If not, it's a new object to insert. You can if it has a version field assigned by Hibernate: if the version is 0, it has never been inserted. If not, it has been inserted. If it doesn't have any of those two, you can't know. Since you call persist(), your intentio is to insert a new object in the DB. So Hibernate does it, and fails because it already exists.

Comment: BTW, neither the javadoc nor the spec says that it should throw an IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the persist method spec below:

```
/**
 * Make an entity instance managed and persistent.
 * @param entity
 * @throws EntityExistsException if the entity already exists.
 * (The EntityExistsException may be thrown when the persist
 * operation is invoked, or the EntityExistsException or
 * another PersistenceException may be thrown at flush or commit
 * time.)
 * @throws IllegalStateException if this EntityManager has been closed.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if not an entity
 * @throws TransactionRequiredException if invoked on a
 * container-managed entity manager of type
 * PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION and there is
 * no transaction.
 */
public void persist(Object entity);
```

The method should only throw IllegalStateException if the EntityManager is closed. Since your ID attribute has a value and the object is outside the persistence scope, the JPA will try to persist it, handling the Entity as a new Entity.